# How to create Multiple IP addresses with terraform which are not in reserved IP address range?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am unable to create private IP with terraform with "count" in-built variable.

It errors out stating that IP address in "reserved IP range".

Please find below my code block.

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tf_ax_nic" {
  count=5
  name                = "subnet_app_aos_nic_${count.index}"
  location            = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf_rg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf_rg.name}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ax_${count.index}.ip"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.tf_sn_ax.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "static"
    private_ip_address            ="10.100.3.${count.index}"
  }

  tags {
    environment = "${var.env}"
  }
}
```

Any hep would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be reserved first four IP addresses in the subnet by Azure and the IP addresses cannot be assigned to resources. You can see the description in the [Private IP address Allocation method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#ip-address-version-1) like this:

> Azure reserves the first four addresses in each subnet address range,
>   so the addresses cannot be assigned to resources. For example, if the
>   subnet's address range is 10.0.0.0/16, addresses 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.3
>   cannot be assigned to resources.

So I think you just need to use the offset as

```
private_ip_address="10.100.3.${count.index+4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to use offset **`private_ip_address="10.100.3.${count.index+5}"`**

Comment: You should explain a bit more fully why you need to do this (zero indexing and reserved IPs in a subnet). Ideally linking to documentation that shows the reserved IPs in a subnet in Azure.