# Terraform Create multiple IP's from CIDR Block

Tags: terraform

i have variable `cidr=10.11.12.0/16`

And resource with count

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "first" {
  count     = "${length(var.instance_names)}"
  provider  = "aws.base"

  subnet_id = "${var.cidr}"

  private_ips = ["${concat(
      list(var.first_network_interface_private_ip),
      var.first_network_interface_private_ip_additional
  )}"]

  source_dest_check = "${var.first_network_interface_source_dest_check_enabled}"

security_groups = [
     "${concat(
      list(aws_security_group.this.id),
      var.first_network_interface_security_group_additional
    )}"
  ]

  depends_on = [
    "aws_security_group.this",
  ]

  tags = "${merge(
    var.tags_global,
    var.tags_module,
    map("Name", format("%s - First Interface", element(var.instance_names, count.index))),
    map("Description", format("%s", element(var.instance_names, count.index)))
  )}"
}
```

i want for every iteration in count to get different IP

i ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122560/how-to-create-multiple-ip-addresses-with-terraform-which-are-not-in-reserved-ip)  and don't know how to extract first three octets from

10.11.12. ,probably need to use regular expressions to get octets from CIDR ?, or there is other solution for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
  private_ips = ["${concat(
      list(cidrhost(var.cidr , count.index + 249)),
      var.first_network_interface_private_ip_additional
  )}"]
```

getting 10.11.12.249/250 IPs for both machines