Terraform create an array/list from a number and a variable with a number of elements
I do have a variable with the first 3 octets of an ip address range, like "172.16.100" and 2 variables with a start ip address (last octet, like 2) and the number of ip address, like 3.
How do I create such a list, so I will get an array/list like:
[ 172.16.100.2, 172.16.100.3, .....]

Or is there a better way to create a range op ip addresses from a starting ip address?
Thanks!

I think you can’t do more, just this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122560/how-to-create-multiple-ip-addresses-with-terraform-which-are-not-in-reserved-ip

You cannot assign IP addresses ranging from '0' to '3' in azure.
The azure reserves the first four addresses in each subnet address range, refer this MS Doc for more details

You can use the range function to generate a list of numbers using a start value, a limit value, and a step value:
range(max)
range(start, limit)
range(start, limit, step)

Example
variable "start_ip_address" {
  type        = string
  description = "The starting IP address in format 'x.x.x' - example '172.16.100'"
  default     = "172.16.100"
}

variable "start_octet" {
  type        = number
  description = "The starting octet in the IP address."
  default     = 4
}

variable "ip_count" {
  type        = number
  description = "Number of IP addresses to generate."
  default     = 5
}

locals {
  ip_addresses = [
    for i in range(var.ip_count) :
    format("%s.%d", var.start_ip_address, i + var.start_octet)
  ]
}

output "ip_addresses" {
  value = local.ip_addresses
}

Running terraform plan:
Changes to Outputs:
  + ip_addresses = [
      + "172.16.100.4",
      + "172.16.100.5",
      + "172.16.100.6",
      + "172.16.100.7",
      + "172.16.100.8",
    ]

